# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, pid

I'm using [Formscanner](http://www.formscanner.org)  and its after processing some Images its giving the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:717)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:950)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1357)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
at com.albertoborsetta.formscanner.api.FormTemplate.findPoints(FormTemplate.java:852)
at com.albertoborsetta.formscanner.model.FormScannerModel.analyzeFiles(FormScannerModel.java:562)
at com.albertoborsetta.formscanner.main.FormScanner.main(FormScanner.java:145)
```

the find points method is as under:

```
public void findPoints(BufferedImage image, int threshold, int density,
        int size) throws FormScannerException {
    height = image.getHeight();
    width = image.getWidth();
    int cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores - 1);
    HashSet<Future<HashMap<String, FormQuestion>>> fieldDetectorThreads = new HashSet<>();

    HashMap<String, FormQuestion> templateFields = template.getFields();
    ArrayList<String> fieldNames = new ArrayList<>(templateFields.keySet());
    Collections.sort(fieldNames);

    for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
        Future<HashMap<String, FormQuestion>> future = threadPool.submit(new FieldDetector(threshold, density, size, this, templateFields.get(fieldName), image));
        fieldDetectorThreads.add(future);
    }

    for (Future<HashMap<String, FormQuestion>> thread : fieldDetectorThreads) {
        try {
            HashMap<String, FormQuestion> threadFields = thread.get();
            for (String fieldName : threadFields.keySet()) {
                FormQuestion field = threadFields.get(fieldName);
                fields.put(fieldName, field);
                for (Entry<String, FormPoint> point : field.getPoints().entrySet()) {
                    if (point.getValue() != null) {
                        pointList.add(point.getValue());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new FormScannerException(e.getCause());
        }
    }

    threadPool.shutdown();

}
```

the above function is being called in the loop and the number of java processes grows and at a point it raises the above exception.

Is there any way that these threads got killed after the shutdown method is called. I'm not a java developer. I did some R&D. But I'm not successful.

Comment: Are you running a 32 or 64 bit JVM? What's the OS used? What are the memory settings (Xmx, Xms,Xss...)?

Comment: The pool is suppose to limit the number of thread running and you have a `thread.get` that wait for each thread to end. So unless you are calling this methods in new threads (that would be visible in the stacktrace), I don't see how this could overload. **But of course, it could be the first running FieldDetectors instance that take all the memory available**. What will do the FieldDetector instance ?

Comment: Im using ubuntu 64bit with openjdk

Comment: @AxelH i dont have idea about it.

Comment: I see that you have posted a question on their google forum. Searching there, I notice that there is a post [here](http://www.formscanner.org/forum?place=msg%2Fformscanner%2FZnzGoP7AheM%2FJsjK64YTQ20J) talking about a problem of memory usage only cleaning when the app is closed. So I would say that the API have memory leaking, the previous files are not release correctly, leading to your problem after a lot of file processes. It is opensource so I could try to check the source this week-end If you have time. I am curious about OMR now ;)

Comment: @AxelH So how can I fix this memory leak? Please float some idea. As the number process of the java in ps list grows continuously...

Comment: You can't unless you find it in that software and correct it yourself, if this is the reason, that a bug from the developer team that miss it. Of course, restarting the app to kill the previous JVM thread do the job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147344/discussion-between-baran-and-axelh).

Answer (score 2):

The problem come from the `Set<Future>` used to hold every instance to check them later.

In chat, you told me you were checking 120.000files. That means there are that many Future created, when the pool find a slot, it will create a `Thread` to execute the `Callable`.

Since the `Set` hold every instance, the `Thread` are not garbage collected, that what give you the leaking. You need to remove every used `Future` to let the `GC` clear the memory for the next `Thread`.

Using an iterator instead of the loop itself is simple and let you remove the current instance before usage

```
Iterator<Future<HashMap<String, FormQuestion>>> iterator = fieldDetectorThreads.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    //get the next instance
    Future<HashMap<String, FormQuestion>> thread = iterator.next();
    //Remove it from the set
    iterator.remove();

    //then work on that instance just like before
    try {
        HashMap<String, FormQuestion> threadFields = thread.get();
        for (String fieldName : threadFields.keySet()) {
            FormQuestion field = threadFields.get(fieldName);
            fields.put(fieldName, field);
            for (Entry<String, FormPoint> point : field.getPoints().entrySet()) {
                if (point.getValue() != null) {
                    pointList.add(point.getValue());
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        throw new FormScannerException(e.getCause());
    }
}
```

This solution is not tested but this should be able to release the memory fast enough.

But if the loop to submit the request took to much time to end (120k future to generate before checking the first one), this would break before every request are sended.

In that case, it might be necessary to split that logic in two threads, one to send request, one to check the result until the first thread is over and the set is empty.

---

Just in case, I would add after the loop a shutdown request

```
threadPool.shutdown();
```

it should not be necessary, but strangely my test program don't end without it ... even if every thread have been processed, they seems to keep existing and blocking the main thread.

Comment: I have reverted the code when i have processed 1000 sheets it have the same effect 513 processes were running as I changed as per your suggestion.